# Поиск слова в текста с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qt, c++

Помогите составить регулярное выражения для поиска слов в тексте.

Начало слова: буква или знак `#`. В слове также может присутствовать знак `_`.

Конец слова: любой символ или знак.

К примеру, результатом данного кода:

```
QRegExp rx("регулярное выражение");
QString str = "MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()";
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    qDebug() << rx.cap(1);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

должен быть:

> MainWindow
>
> on_pushButton_clicked

Comment: Строки всегда будут разделены двойным двоеточием? Может быть проще разбить строку по `"::"` и из второй части вытащить всё то, что соответствует `\w` ?

Comment: Нет. Текстом будет выступать любой код С++/Qt.

Comment: А цифры не используются в словах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А это не работает:

```
/([a-zA-Z#_]+)/gm
```

http://regex101.com/r/eX1iH8

Comment: Отлично - работает! Вы не могли бы мне по подробней объяснить как работает знак `+`? Я никак не могу понять его роль в регулярных выражениях.

Comment: Одно совпадение или больше выражению, тоесть будет искать все символы в строке, пока не наткнется на неудовлетворяющий выражению символ. Как-то так

Comment: Можете по ссылке в ответе поставить эксперимент - удалите плюс и посмотрите на вывод.

Comment: Если слово не должно содержать # в середине или конце, а также не должно начинаться на цифру, но может содержать цифры в середине, то посмотрите на это выражение:

http://regex101.com/r/wB9bM7

Comment: @MDJHD, Ваше второе выражение не подходит для слов *из одной* буквы.

Наверное надо так

    [a-zA-Z#][a-zA-Z0-9_]*

(я добавил цифры, но не для первого символа слова).

Т.е. в начале всегда одна буква или `#` и потом необязательно (@derkode, это о звездочке) сколько угодно букв, цифр и подчеркиваний.

--

Только вот для разбора текста программы это в общем случае неправильно, поскольку такие имена могут быть в комментариях, строковах константах и внутри неактивных частей \#if ... препроцессора.

Comment: @avp, ну да, спасибо.